# Bigquery query performance when using starts_with() on a table of 12Mil rows

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a table company_totals, that has the following schema -

| column_name | column_data_type |
| --- | --- |
| company | STRING |
| link | STRING |
| full_count | FLOAT |
| starts_with_count | FLOAT |

Number of rows = 12,000,000. Table size = 1.6 GB. CLUSTERED BY = company link. SEARCH INDEX created on column = link.

I have the following select statement which is taking beyond 6 hours and the execution results in timeout -  **Operation timed out after 6.0 hours. Consider reducing the amount of work performed by your operation so that it can complete within this limit.)**

```sql
SELECT first_table.company, first_table.link, null as full_count, SUM(second_table.full_count) AS starts_with_count 
FROM company_totals first_table, company_totals second_table 
WHERE STARTS_WITH(second_table.link, first_table.link)
group by first_table.company, first_table.link
```

The above query calculates values of the column **starts_with_count** which is the sum of values of another column **full_count**, based on a **starts_with()** condition. In the **company_totals** table, the column **starts_with_count** is what I want to fill. I have added the expected values for this column manually to show my expectation. Other column values are already present in the table. The **starts_with_count** value is **sum (full_count)** where its **link** appears in other rows.

| company | link | full_count | starts_with_count (expected) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | http://www.abc.net1 | 1 | 15 (= sum (full_count) where link like 'http://www.abc.net1%') |
| abc | http://www.abc.net1/page1 | 2 | 9 (= sum (full_count) where link like 'http://www.abc.net1/page1%') |
| abc | http://www.abc.net1/page1/folder1 | 3 | 3 (= sum (full_count) where link like 'http://www.abc.net1/page1/folder1%') |
| abc | http://www.abc.net1/page1/folder2 | 4 | 4 |
| abc | http://www.abc.net1/page2 | 5 | 5 |
| xyz | http://www.xyz.net1/ | 6 | 21 |
| xyz | http://www.xyz.net1/page1/ | 7 | 15 |
| xyz | http://www.xyz.net1/page1/file1 | 8 | 8 |

Highly appreciate any help in this issue.

Comment: Would you add one more join condition and see if it works ? 
`WHERE STARTS_WITH(second_table.link, first_table.link) AND first_table.company = second_table.company`

Comment: Hi @jaytiger - Actually currently, the records count for company xyz is just 3 records and count for abc is large (12Mil - 3). So majority of time taken during the query is for company abc. So I was wondering how to have the query run faster even when there is a single company with millions of records

Comment: Can you try to help the comparison with the search indexes? use that where `WHERE SEARCH(second_table.link, first_table.link) AND STARTS_WITH(second_table.link, first_table.link) `

Comment: Thanks @guillaumeblaquiere for the suggestion.
Sure, I just tried 
`WHERE SEARCH(second_table.link, first_table.link) AND STARTS_WITH(second_table.link, first_table.link)`
And I see this error - `Argument 2 to BIGQUERYGOOGLESQL:SEARCH must be a literal or query parameter at [8:22]'

I think the second parameter must be a literal, and its not taking a column name

Comment: Hi @bqlearner, The error message indicates that there are not enough resources or because of complex queries or too many jobs are running concurrently, so the  BigQuery job was not able to complete within the specified 6 hours limit. As per this BigQuery [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#query_jobs), if the job should be completed within the 6 hours, if not, it will fail.

Comment: It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue 
tracker under the [BigQuery component](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162659).